# Trim off leading Characters in Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to find a way to remove the IP/domain off the path for an image.

Currently I have this where xxx is the IP address

http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/upload/88/img_2886.jpg

but I need to store this in the DB

/upload/88/img_2886.jpg

I am looking for a way in jquery to trim off any characters before /upload

I cannot look for the IP itself because it could change. it could be an IP address, domain or could contain any numbers of characters before /upload. Is this possible with Jquery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently I am using

```
$("#ajaximageid").val($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
```

but of course this is giving me a full path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.URL)?

```
var url = new URL("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/upload/88/img_2886.jpg");
console.log(url.pathname);
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know about .pathname that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If the URL is always in this sheme:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/path
```

You can trim of the String after the first slash after the `http://`.

```
var url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/upload/88/img_2886.jpg";
var src = url.substring(url.indexOf("/", 7));
```

With `str.indexOf("/")` you get the position of the slash and then cutt the part before off.

This code will return:

```
/upload/88/img_2886.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks but the URL is not always going to be the same. It could be an IP address or domain.

Comment: @Rob It can be an IP adress / domain; the only thing it needs is the `http://` in front of it - this code will work then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex replace, then the regex will be `^.*?/upload/` and the replace string will be `/upload/`